# Google Adwords Traffic Estimator Service and Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api

I've downloaded a code sample that looks for particular keywords and pulls some metrics. I've noticed a lot of Google Adwords API examples are compliant with python 3.x so I'm wondering if there is an issue with that? See below for code sample:

```
from googleads import adwords


def main(client):
  # Initialize appropriate service.
  traffic_estimator_service = client.GetService(
      'TrafficEstimatorService', version='v201609')

  # Construct selector object and retrieve traffic estimates.
  keywords = [
      {'text': 'mars cruise', 'matchType': 'BROAD'},
      {'text': 'cheap cruise', 'matchType': 'PHRASE'},
      {'text': 'cruise', 'matchType': 'EXACT'}
  ]
  negative_keywords = [
      {'text': 'moon walk', 'matchType': 'BROAD'}
  ]
  keyword_estimate_requests = []
  for keyword in keywords:
    keyword_estimate_requests.append({
        'keyword': {
            'xsi_type': 'Keyword',
            'matchType': keyword['matchType'],
            'text': keyword['text']
        }
    })

  for keyword in negative_keywords:
    keyword_estimate_requests.append({
        'keyword': {
            'xsi_type': 'Keyword',
            'matchType': keyword['matchType'],
            'text': keyword['text']
        },
        'isNegative': 'true'
    })

  # Create ad group estimate requests.
  adgroup_estimate_requests = [{
      'keywordEstimateRequests': keyword_estimate_requests,
      'maxCpc': {
          'xsi_type': 'Money',
          'microAmount': '1000000'
      }
  }]

  # Create campaign estimate requests.
  campaign_estimate_requests = [{
      'adGroupEstimateRequests': adgroup_estimate_requests,
      'criteria': [
          {
              'xsi_type': 'Location',
              'id': '2840'  # United States.
          },
          {
              'xsi_type': 'Language',
              'id': '1000'  # English.
          }
      ],
  }]

  # Create the selector.
  selector = {
      'campaignEstimateRequests': campaign_estimate_requests,
  }

  # Optional: Request a list of campaign-level estimates segmented by
  # platform.
  selector['platformEstimateRequested'] = True

  # Get traffic estimates.
  estimates = traffic_estimator_service.get(selector)

  campaign_estimate = estimates['campaignEstimates'][0]

  # Display the campaign level estimates segmented by platform.
  if 'platformEstimates' in campaign_estimate:
    platform_template = ('Results for the platform with ID: "%d" and name: '
                         '"%s".')
    for platform_estimate in campaign_estimate['platformEstimates']:
      platform = platform_estimate['platform']
      DisplayEstimate(platform_template % (platform['id'],
                                           platform['platformName']),
                      platform_estimate['minEstimate'],
                      platform_estimate['maxEstimate'])

  # Display the keyword estimates.
  if 'adGroupEstimates' in campaign_estimate:
    ad_group_estimate = campaign_estimate['adGroupEstimates'][0]
    if 'keywordEstimates' in ad_group_estimate:
      keyword_estimates = ad_group_estimate['keywordEstimates']
      keyword_template = ('Results for the keyword with text "%s" and match '
                          'type "%s":')

      keyword_estimates_and_requests = zip(keyword_estimates,
                                           keyword_estimate_requests)

      for keyword_tuple in keyword_estimates_and_requests:
        if keyword_tuple[1].get('isNegative', False):
          continue
        keyword = keyword_tuple[1]['keyword']
        keyword_estimate = keyword_tuple[0]
        DisplayEstimate(keyword_template % (keyword['text'],
                                            keyword['matchType']),
                        keyword_estimate['min'], keyword_estimate['max'])


def _CalculateMean(min_est, max_est):
  if min_est and max_est:
    return (float(min_est) + float(max_est)) / 2.0
  else:
    return None


def _FormatMean(mean):
  if mean:
    return '%.2f' % mean
  else:
    return 'N/A'


def DisplayEstimate(message, min_estimate, max_estimate):
  """Displays mean average cpc, position, clicks, and total cost for estimate.
  Args:
    message: str message to display for the given estimate.
    min_estimate: sudsobject containing a minimum estimate from the
      TrafficEstimatorService response.
    max_estimate: sudsobject containing a maximum estimate from the
      TrafficEstimatorService response.
  """
  # Find the mean of the min and max values.
  mean_avg_cpc = (_CalculateMean(min_estimate['averageCpc']['microAmount'],
                                 max_estimate['averageCpc']['microAmount'])
                  if 'averageCpc' in min_estimate else None)
  mean_avg_pos = (_CalculateMean(min_estimate['averagePosition'],
                                 max_estimate['averagePosition'])
                  if 'averagePosition' in min_estimate else None)
  mean_clicks = _CalculateMean(min_estimate['clicksPerDay'],
                               max_estimate['clicksPerDay'])
  mean_total_cost = _CalculateMean(min_estimate['totalCost']['microAmount'],
                                   max_estimate['totalCost']['microAmount'])

  print (message)
  print ('Estimated average CPC: %s' % _FormatMean(mean_avg_cpc))
  print ('Estimated ad position: %s' % _FormatMean(mean_avg_pos))
  print ('Estimated daily clicks: %s' % _FormatMean(mean_clicks))
  print ('Estimated daily cost: %s' % _FormatMean(mean_total_cost))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Initialize client object.
  adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

  main(adwords_client)
```

Here is the error message:

```
(Money) not-found
path: "Money", not-found
(Keyword) not-found
path: "Keyword", not-found
(Keyword) not-found
path: "Keyword", not-found
(Keyword) not-found
path: "Keyword", not-found
(Keyword) not-found
path: "Keyword", not-found
(Location) not-found
path: "Location", not-found
(Language) not-found
path: "Language", not-found
<suds.sax.document.Document object at 0x03BF1D10>
Server raised fault in response.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 82, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 132, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 613, in send
    reply = self.options.transport.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 94, in send
    raise TransportError(e.msg, e.code, e.fp)
suds.transport.TransportError: Internal Server Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\adwords test - Copy (2).py", line 177, in <module>
    main(adwords_client)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\adwords test - Copy (2).py", line 95, in main
    estimates = traffic_estimator_service.get(selector)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 696, in MakeSoapRequest
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 692, in MakeSoapRequest
    for arg in args])
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 521, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 581, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 619, in send
    description=tostr(e), original_soapenv=original_soapenv)
  File "C:\Users\sfroese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 670, in process_reply
    raise WebFault(fault, replyroot)
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: '[AuthenticationError.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_IS_REQUIRED @ ; trigger:'<null>']'
```

Comment: Looks as if you didn't modify your .yaml file ? You are loading from storage so your Adwords API credentials need to be in that file. Here's more info on [AuthenticationError.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_IS_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/common-errors#AuthenticationError.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_IS_REQUIRED)

Comment: Where are the not-found messages from? suds?

Comment: Any news about that messages? I've got the same..

Answer (score 0):

You should set client_customer_id in your googleads.yaml file . you can get client_customer_id from your manager account. go to your manager account and add client then copy your id from upright corner of screen. in googleads.yaml file paste that id to client_customer_id .